# NSURLConnection Delegate Methods Not Called In Generic Class

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a test class that tries to reach to google with a `NSURLConnection`. If I try to make it generic, the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods are never called.

```
class Remote<T: NSObject>: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
//class Remote: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    var data = NSMutableData()

    func connect(query:NSString) {
        var url =  NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com")!
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var conn = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    }


    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        LF.log("didReceiveResponse")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
        LF.log("didReceiveData")
        self.data.appendData(conData)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        LF.log("didFinished")
        //println(self.data)
    }


    deinit {
        println("deiniting")
    }
}
```

To test it (comment/uncomment the first/second line to compare):

```
    let remote = Remote<NSObject>()
    //let remote = Remote()
    remote.connect("")
```

Any idea please?

Update1: to answer comment 1, it's a REST client that handles network connection and parsing for you. I'd write a blog about this later (since it's still under development), but to give you the idea here's some demo code from my project:

```
        let client = ICRestClient<ICCategoryModel>(api:IC.api.category_list)
        client.func_array = {
            (results: [ICCategoryModel]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            block!(results, error)
        }
        client.execute()
```

And ICCategoryModel is like:

```
class ICSubCategoryModel: ICModel {
    var name: String?
    var category_id: Int = 0
}
```

The idea is that you pass the API URL in, you get an array (or error) with some reflected objects instead of Dictionary. It's from my LSwift library and supports various authentications methods (buildin-parameters, cookie, header, authentication challenge etc.)

Comment: What is your purpose for creating a generic class? What problem are you trying to solve with that approach?

Comment: I added update1 with a demo. It is much easier to use than CoreData - the main idea is that in real world in most cases we only need simple technology like JSON, Parse, etc. and solutions like XML, AWS are too complex. To build simple solutions however, sometimes we need to write some uncommon codes. BTW `swift` is much less flexible than `objc` but I simply like the syntax of `swift`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problem is that I can't access the delegate object of `NSURLConnection`. I came up with a solution by creating another RemoteDelegate class, which is not generic type, and set it as the delegate of "conn". It works for now but it's just a work-around, and I'm still looking for the answer to the question.

My delegate class:

```
class LRestConnectionDelegate: NSObject {

    var func_done: ((NSURLResponse?, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)?
    var credential: NSURLCredential?
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
            challenge.sender.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
        } else if let credential = credential {
            challenge.sender.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge)
        } else {
            LF.log("REST connection will challenge", connection)
        }
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse a_response: NSURLResponse) {
        //LF.log("CONNECTION response", response)
        response = a_response
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data_received: NSData) {
        //LF.log("CONNECTION data", data.length)
        data.appendData(data_received)
    }
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
        //LF.log("CONNECTION finished", connection)
        if func_done != nil {
            func_done!(response, data, nil)
        }
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        //LF.log("CONNECTION failed", error)
        if let func_done = func_done {
            func_done(response, nil, error)
        }
    }
    deinit {
        //LF.log("DELEGATE deinit", self)
    }
}
```

And this works in `class LRestClient<T: LFModel>`:

```
        let delegate = LRestConnectionDelegate()
        delegate.credential = credential
        delegate.func_done = func_done
        connection = NSURLConnection(request:request, delegate:delegate, startImmediately:true)
```

Comment: For those who came cross the same problem as I did, if you can live with iOS 7+ perhaps it would be good to start with `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection`. I plan to rewrite all my connection code using `NSURLSession` to support response body with a HTTP code that's not 2xx, which is required by some servers.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're using NSURLConnection synchronously, you have to schedule the operation in the main run loop. Add the following code to the end of your `connect` function:

`conn?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)`

Alternatively, set `startImmediately` to `NO` and call `conn?.start()`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with this question, but yes if you're experiencing some similar issue (`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` not called) you can try this. You can also try moving conn out, make it a class property. This question however is only about generic type.

Comment: No it isn't. He's wondering why his delegate methods aren't being called. It's more than likely because the connection isn't being started by scheduling it in the run loop.

Comment: Sorry man I'm the one who asked, and with or without the `<T: NSObject>` part makes the change.