# Set a generic class as a delegate in swift

Tags: swift, generics, delegates

I have a class `XMLUtil`, that wraps some xml parsing functionality. The class has one generic parameter `T`. The class also acts as the `NSXMLParserDelegate` to the `NSXMLParser` delegator.

```
class XMLUtil<T>: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate{
    ...
    ...

    init(){
        parser = NSXMLParser(data: NSData)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }

    ...
    ...
    //delegate method implementations

}
```

**The problem:**

When my XMLUtil class is a generic class, the delegate methods never get called. They do however, when I implement the `XMLUtil` class without generic parameters

These two questions seem to be of similar nature

[Swift Generic class as delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324105/swift-generic-class-as-delegate)

[NSURLConnection Delegate Methods Not Called In Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886104/nsurlconnection-delegate-methods-not-called-in-generic-class)

Is there anything in the documentations that would explain this behavior? Is this intended or is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, the links that you cite to tell you the answer. A generic class cannot be the delegate for a Cocoa class. It's not a bug... it is a feature that has not been implemented yet. I don't know if it will ever be implemented. It may not be possible. But it is a current limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When my XMLUtil class is a generic class

But Objective-C knows nothing of generic classes. So there is no way to show your XMLUtil class to Objective-C. Thus, it cannot serve as NSXMLParser's delegate; NSXMLParser is an Objective-C class and cannot see your XMLUtil class if it is generic.

One easy way to see this is to try to mark your XMLUtil class as `@objc`. You will fail; the compiler will stop you. There is no way to show this class to Objective-C.

Comment: Interesting. So does the compiler just act as though I the line `parser.delegate = self` didn't exist? Also, why doesn't it stop me from assigning a generic class as a delegate to an Objective-C class?

Comment: "Also, why doesn't it stop me from assigning a generic class as a delegate to an Objective-C class" That is a _very_ good question. You would think the compiler would stop you earlier, somehow. Personally, I regard this as a bug; the compiler should be more helpful. Letting you do something that isn't in fact going to work is not very nice.

Comment: I take it that declaring the individual delegate methods `@objc` doesn't help? You can't say e.g. `@objc func parserDidStartDocument` etc. and have them be called? I wouldn't expect it to work but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hi Matt, quick question, how can I set delegate = self, if I cannot instantiate an object because it is a generic class which I don't have access to in the other class, yet I want the generics class to call a function in the other class, hence the need for delegate?